# Draw Graphics on program start; PaintComponent never called

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

This seems like such a simple problem but somehow I haven't been able to google the answer.  Tutorials seem to skim over the beginning and I don't see how their program is different than mine. All I'm trying to do is create a JPanel and use the Graphics class to draw things on it, on program start up.

I created a super simplified version of the program that also doesn't work:

```
public class Thing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test");
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        OtherThing panel = new OtherThing();

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class OtherThing extends JPanel
{
    public OtherThing()
    {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        repaint();
    }
    public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setForeground(Color.red);
        System.out.println("start");
        g.drawOval(0,0,50,50);
        g.drawLine(0,0 , 100, 100);
        g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
        System.out.println("After");

    }
}
```

The Sytem.out.println's are never printed out. PaintComponent is never called.  In some of the tutorials I looked at they made it sound as simply as that repaint calls paintcomponent, but in my program paintcomponent is never called.

I just want the graphics to draw on startup.

Comment: Change `public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)` to `@Override public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)` for an helpful compiler message..

Comment: I'm confused... it told me theres nothing to override? JPanel doesnt have PaintComponent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is key sensitive. The

```
public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)
```

must be

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

Comment: And doesn't need to be `public`